# Elements in form displayed below each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem that I've already asked about but with no helpful results.

The problem is that I have a search filter with form element that holds several elements like input fields, checkboxes. I use this form to filter results od pdf reports. I've previously used Bootstrap 3 and all the elements were displayed one after another in a line. If there were more than 4 elements, then 3 were in one row, the 4th was in 2nd row, etc.

I switched to Bootstrap 4 and now all elements are shown below each other instead in line. I don't understand what is wrong in this html view because it used to work in BTS 3. Here are some images:

**How it needs to be (before Bootstrap 4):**

[image]

**How it is now (with Bootstrap 4 - PROBLEM):**

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="data-container" class="form-horizontal details-content">
<div class="page-title  col-md-12">@SharedResources.Index.Report - @ViewBag.reportName</div>
<br />
<!-- left side -->

<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="if: editParameters() || showOpenFilterButton()">
  <br />

  <div class="card panel-info mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h6 class="card-title">
        <span>@SharedResources.Index.ReportDetails</span>
      </h6>
      <div id="grid-picker-resident" class="grid-picker" data-bind="visible: showOpenFilterButton()">
        <span class="pull-right fa fa-hand-o-down" style="margin-top:-15px;" title="@SharedResources.Index.ShowHideParameters" data-bind="click: showParameters"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body" data-bind="if :showParam() || editParameters() ">
      <form class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: submitReportData">
        <div id="input-holder" data-bind="foreach:mainData">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;" class="form-group row">
              <label class="control-label" data-bind="text: DisplayText, attr : {'for' : Name}"></label>
              <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Input' -->
              <input style="width:100%" type="text" data-bind="value: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
              <!-- /ko -->
              <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'Checkbox' -->
              <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Value" class="checkbox input-sm">
              <!-- /ko -->
              <!-- ko if:  (DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownMonths' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownActive' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownStatus' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownsRequestType' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownGender' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownStatusActive'  || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownShifts' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownRoomGroups') && !MultiValue() -->
              <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', value: Value, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
              <!-- /ko -->
              <!-- ko if:  (DisplayMode() == 'Dropdown' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownMonths' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownActive' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownStatus' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownsRequestType' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownGender' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownStatusActive'  || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownShifts' || DisplayMode() == 'DropdownRoomGroups') && MultiValue() -->
              <select data-bind="options: ParameterOptions, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'label', selectedOptions: Value, validationElement: Value" multiple style="height:150px !important;" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
              <!-- /ko -->
              <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'AutoComplete' -->
              <input type="text" data-bind="validationElement: Value, attr : {'id':'autocomplete_' + Name()}" placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.AutocompleteMessage" class="form-control input-sm">
              <!-- /ko -->
              <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DatePicker' -->
              <input type="text" data-bind="datePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
              <!-- /ko -->
              <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'DateTimePicker' -->
              <input type="text" data-bind="dateTimePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
              <!-- /ko -->
              <!-- ko if:  DisplayMode() == 'TimePicker' -->
              <input type="text" data-bind="timePicker: Value, attr:{'id': Name() }, validationElement: Value" class="form-control input-sm">
              <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" style="margin:20px !important;" class="btn pull-right" id="generateReport"><em class="fa fa-repeat"></em> @SharedResources.Index.ShowReport</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ko if:  reportRequested() -->
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="card panel-info panel-samewidth mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h6 class="card-title">
        <span>@SharedResources.Index.ReportPreview</span>
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div id="reportPanel" class="card-body">
      <iframe id="reportPreview" src="" scrolling="yes" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="yes" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%" data-bind="event:{ load: reportLoaded }"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

What I've tried so far:

- Add 'row' attribute to class of 'form-group'
- Remove 'div' element with 'input-holder' class
- Replace 'form-horizontal' with 'form-inline'

Nothing worked. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Maybe `<input style="width:100%" type="text" data-bind="value: Value" class="form-control input-sm">` or more particular `style="width:100%"` causes this behavior, since it means "100% of parent element" it may occupy the whole space. Just a guess tho

Comment: @D.Schaller the width is attributed to one of the input elements, so it didnt help removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried FORM using the class form-inline inside DIV with class container?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">OD</span><input type="number" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"></span>                  
         <span class="input-group-addon">DO</span><input type="number" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```